# Application object cannot be used in ASP.NET web page

Tags: asp.net

How to use Application object in the web page?

I thought it should be something like Session object.
But when I use Application, it shows the Reference like

```
System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application
```

Obviously, it's not the one I'm looking for.

Has it been discarded in .NET 4?

If yes, what should I use to replace the Application object.

Comment: Where do you want to access it? `Application` is a property of `Page` that returns the [`HttpApplicationState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to this one

[Page.Application Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aabkk236%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Gets the HttpApplicationState object for the current Web request.

Answer (score 1):

```
<% 
    this.Application["test"] = "some value";
%>
```

inside a WebForm should work. And in the code behind it's the same story:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Application["test"] = "some value";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aabkk236%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (HttpApplicationState) property is very much there.

Seems you have some references that are causing the confusion.

In your CS code on a Page you should be able to use it

```
this.Application["key"] = myObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you try to access it from an ASP.NET page. `Application` is a property of `Page` that returns the [`HttpApplicationState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Page.Application["Foo"] != null)
    {
        // ... 
    }
}
```

If you want to access it from a static context, you can use [`HttpContext.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx):

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Application["Foo"] != null){ }
```